# Can't see my extension in Module List after copying it in root folder in opencart

Tags: opencart, extension-modules

i have copied the files of the extension in the root folder of the wesite (working on the localhost) but it doesn't show in the module list when i open the module list in the backend. Can somebody help me.

Comment: which module are you trying to install, does it required vqmod ?

Comment: i am using a module to turn my products on or off and it doesn't require vqmod.

Comment: i have also tried it using vqmod but its still not working.

Comment: could you give me the module (name) and the version of oc your trying to install